# Saber quando meu list está vindo com valores na sequencia

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho um `List<int>`:

> [2,3,5,4,6]

Por mais que não estejam na ordem, ele é uma sequencia de numeros (2,3,4,5,6)
Como faço para validar isso?

> OBS: Sempre haverão 5 posições e os números serão de 1 a 6

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOpt. sua pergunta não está muito clara. O que extamente você quer validar? se os números aí dentro estão entre 1 e 6? Se estabelecem uma sequencia (mesmo fora da ordem)? ...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, acho que nessa frase: `Por mais que não estejam na ordem, ele é uma sequencia de numeros (2,3,4,5,6) Como faço para validar isso?` ele deixa bem claro isso.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos na verdade é exatamente aí que deixou confuso. Ele fez duas afirmações: `é uma sequência` e `é de 1 a 6`. Se é para estabelecer uma regra, o correto seria `devem ser uma sequência` e `devem ser de 1 a 6` (o que limita a duas possibilidades válidas: 1,2,3,4,5 **OU** 2,3,4,5,6). Com a sua edição você alterou a pergunta para refletir a sua interpretação. Pode ser que esteja correta. Deixa ver se foi isso mesmo que ele quis dizer

Comment: Não editei a ponto de mudar o sentido da pergunta, apenas deixei mais visível o que já estava separado, era apenas uma observação.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos [No _post_ que ele fez no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535273/listint-identifying-sequences-and-repeats) acho que ele tentou detalhar mais, mas para mim (e pelo visto para os outros também) o que ele quer continua um mistério.

Comment: Boa noite pessoal, pois é, isso ta um mistério mesmo, mas vou tentar explicar melhor por aqui... tenho uma lista com 5 numeros aleatorios de 1 a 6...e tenho 2 regras de sequencia que preciso saber....por exemplo: Regra 1 - ter pelo menos 4 numeros em ordem numérica...que seria isso [1,2,3,4,6] ou isso tambem [2,1,3,4,6]...e a Regra 2 - ter os 5 numeros em ordem numerica...que poderia ser isso [1,2,3,4,5] ou isso [2,3,4,5,6] ou tambem isso [6,2,3,4,5]....sera que ficou melhor a explicação?? Desde já agradeço toda a ajuda de vocÊs...abraço

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) junto ao [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx). Supondo que sua list chama `lista`, veja como ficaria:

```
lista.SequenceEqual(lista.OrderBy(x => x))
```

Essa linha retornará um boolean dizendo se está ordenado ou não.

> Veja funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L442nX).

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar a seguinte função:

```
public bool hasNumberSequence(List<int> numbers)
{
    numbers.Sort();

    int numerosSequenciais = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] != (numbers[i - 1] + 1))
            numerosSequenciais = 0;
        else
            numerosSequenciais++;
    }

    return numerosSequenciais >= 4;
}
```

Essa função retorna `true` em caso de existir uma sequência de ao menos 4 números na lista de `int` e `false` em caso de não existir.

**Exemplos de Uso**

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>() { 0, 3, 5, 4, 6 };
Console.WriteLine(hasNumberSequence().ToString(numeros)); // True

numeros = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 5, 4, 6 };
Console.WriteLine(hasNumberSequence(numeros).ToString()); // True

numeros = new List<int>() { 2, 1, 0, 4, 6 };
Console.WriteLine(hasNumberSequence(numeros).ToString()); // False
```

Comment: Ok Roberto, com essa função ele me traz verdadeiro se as 5 posições estão numa sequencia, essa parte beleza...mas tambem preciso de uma outra logica que se tiver 4 posições na sequencia ele me retorna true tambem...exemplo [2,3,1,4,6] que nesse caso são os numero 1,2,3,4...entendeu? Abraço

Comment: @Arthur alterei a resposta de acordo com sua explicação nos comentários, veja se soluciona.

Comment: Obrigado pela força, mas estou fazendo alguns testes aqui e esse list por exemplo não esta aceitando como uma sequencia com 4 numeros [1,2,3,3,4], o que eu entendi é que quando chega no segundo numero 3 ele zera a contagem. Pode me auxiliar com isso por favor?
Abraço

Comment: também fiz um outro teste simples passando [1,2,3,4,5] e ele está me retornando apenas 4 numeros sequenciais, nesse caso teria que voltar 5 certo?